# Função dentro de map retornando undefined

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho uma função map que precisa confirmar se determinados valores existem para que certas lacunas possam ser preenchidas.

A função que testa se os valores existem foi criada porém, na hora de retornar o valor dentro do map ela retorna como undefined, o console.log() dentro da função me garante que ela está funcionando porém, no map ela está indo como undefined.

O response.data.items vem de uma base do google onde estou usando map para retirar determinados dados, como nem todos os dados possuem o item.pagemap.localbusiness, eu criei um if que verificar se ela existe antes de tentar usar o map nela. Segue o código do map:

```
placesInfo = [...response.data.items.map((item) => {
        const isExist = (obj, src) => {
            console.log (obj.map(item => item[src])) //Esse console.log me garante que a função está funcionando
            return obj.map(item => item[src])
        }
        if(!item.pagemap.localbusiness) {
            return {
                title: item.title,
                link: item.link,
                snippet: item.snippet,
                name: '',
                email: '',
                telephone: '',
                address: ''
            }
        }
        else return {
            title: item.title,
            link: item.link,
            snippet: item.snippet,
            name: isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'name') ? item.name: null, //Aqui o valor sempre vem como undefined
            email: isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'email') ? item.email: null, //Aqui o valor sempre vem como undefined
            telephone: isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'telephone') ? item.telephone: null, //Aqui o valor sempre vem como undefined
            address: isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'address') ? item.address: null, //Aqui o valor sempre vem como undefined
        }})]
```

Ao final do map, tenho um array com resultados dessa forma:

```
{
    title: 'Cláudio Souza Barbearia - Barbearia em Muriqui',
    link: 'https://claudio-souza-barbearia.negocio.site/',
    snippet: 'Cláudio Souza Barbearia. Barbearia em Muriqui. Abre amanhã às 09:00. \n' +
      'Solicitar cotaçãoLigar agoraVer rotasWhatsAppEnvie-nos uma mensagemEntrar \n' +
    name: undefined,
    email: undefined,
    telephone: undefined,
    address: undefined
  }
```

Porém, o console.log lá em cima me garante que existem resultados a serem preenchidos onde temos undefined, o console.log me retorna coisas como:

```
    [
  'Wagner Salão de Beleza Masculino',
  'Wagner Salão de Beleza Masculino',
  'DILMA ESTÉTICA.COM',
  'BARBEARIA COPACABANA - COPACABANA',
  'SALAO E BARBEARIA INTERNACIONAL',
  'BARBEARIA NOSSA SENHORA DA PENHA',
  'BARBEARIA ATLÂNTICA LTDA',
  'BARBEARIA BLUE STAR',
  'BARBEARIA TRÊS AMIGOS LTDA',
  'AUGUSTO GUEDES ALVES',
  'VICENTE PINHEIRO DOS PASSOS',
  'BARBEARIA',
  'CABELEIREIRO KAIOS',
  'SALAO ELITE BARBEARIA LTDA',
  'IRMÃOS FERNANDES BARBEARIA LTDA',
  'SALÃO NOSSA SENHORA PAZ BARBEARIA',
  'SALÃO E BARBEARIA PAPISO'
    ]
    [ 'Barbearia Rodrigues' ]
```

Alguma solução possível?

Comment: Por favor, elabore um [mcve] que demonstre o problema citado. No trecho de código que colocou na pergunta, muitos objetos não foram definidos e as funções não existem, o que torna impossível reproduzir o erro citado.

Comment: Atualizei no post, vê se ficou um pouco mais claro, por favor

Comment: O que me chamou a atenção é que nessa expressão `isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'name') ? item.name: null` sempre vai retornar `item.name`, pois para `isExist()` o resultado é sempre um array, mesmo que vazio, e o operador `?` induzirá o resultado de `isExist()` a um booleano. Pois bem em javascript um array independente de estar ou não vazio sempre é convertido ao booleano `true` : exemplo `console.log([])` . O que implica  que `item.name`, `item.email`, `item.telephone` e `item.address` não estão definidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se esta retornando `undefined` é pq de fato não está definido. Pelo seu operador ternário. `isExist` está retornando true e eles está tentando acessar o conteúdo de `item`. do contrário não ficaria com `undefined` e sim `null`. Se o `console.log` dentro de `isExists` está recebendo o objeto `item.pagemap.localbusiness` e acessando as keys dentro dele. você deveria está usando `item.pagemap.localbusiness` ao invés de `item` no seu `return`
ou usar o retorno de `isExists` ao invés de apenas usar para verificar no operador ternário. Outro problema é que você parece ter um array de objetos com keys iguais as que você está querendo. Então `isExists` está na verdade, retornando um array simples com todos os valores da key que você buscou.

Supondo que você queira salvar todos os valores, você deveria retornar todo o conteúdo que `isExists` retorna. Caso seja esse o seu caso, substitua pela sintaxe abaixo:

```js
else return {
  title: item.title,
  link: item.link,
  snippet: item.snippet,
  name: isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'name') || null,
  email: isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'email') || null,
  telephone: isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'telephone') || null,
  address: isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'address') || null,
}
```

Comment: Isso é importante *...isExist está retornando true...* .

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado! 
Teria alguma forma de eu garantir que na resposta não venha um array e só pegue o primeiro valor retornado?

Comment: adicione `[0]` após a chamama de `isExists`, exemplo: `name: isExist(item.pagemap.localbusiness, 'name')[0] || null`

Comment: @ArthurLopes Considere aceitar a resposta como a solução, caso tenha respondido sua pergunta.

Comment: Deu tudo certo aqui, muito obrigado, de verdade!